# Oracle SQL query: Delete the oldest duplicate records from the table

Tags: sql, oracle

Current table:

**Users**:

| ID | name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | Aug 15 |
| 001 | Coga | March 1 |
| 002 | Pat | May 10 |

I need to write a query which will find the Persons with the same ID and deletes the oldest record.

I am able to find the oldest record, but how can I delete it within the same query?

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Time)
FROM Users
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM USERS group by ID having count(ID) > 1)
group by ID;
```

**Result**:

| ID | name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Coga | March 1 |

When deleting, I need to delete the exact (oldest) record which has a specific ID and specific Time.

Comment: Maybe have a case on the select and then deleting based on the condition..

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that. The biggest problem is that I need to Delete Record by two exact values ( ID and Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
delete
from   users
where  (id, time) in 
       (select id, time
        from   (select id, time, 
                       row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as rn,
                from   users) sub
        where   rn > 1)
```

It will delete all "duplicates" for a certain person, except the most recent one. The idea is that when you number the occurrences of a certain id, from recent to old, only the records numbered with 1 should be kept.

#### Pseudo-column `ROWID`

As guigui42 mentioned in comments below, the [Oracle specific pseudo-column `rowid`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254) may give a further performance improvement. This would be certainly the case if you do not have an index starting with the `id, time` fields:

```
delete
from   users
where  rowid in 
       (select rowid
        from   (select rowid, 
                       row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as rn,
                from   users) sub
        where   rn > 1)
```

Comment: Maybe using ROWID instead of ID/TIME and EXISTS would be more efficient

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, @guigui42!

Comment: Thanks @trincot for the answer! I have marked your query as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with windows functions:

`ROW_NUMBER` will help you find the first one by `ID` (if there are duplicates by `ID` and `TIME` we'll select just one of them)
`COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY)` will validate that there are    duplicates by `ID`

```
DELETE USERS
WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 
      FROM 
      (SELECT ID, TIME, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIME) AS RN,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) CN
         FROM USERS) U
      WHERE U.ID = USERS.ID
        AND U.TIME = USERS.TIME
        AND U.RN = 1 -- FIRST ONE WITH THAT ID
        AND U.CN > 1 -- WE HAVE MORE THAN ONE
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete 
from 
    USERS 
where
    U_TIME in (select 
                   U_TIME 
               from
                   (select 
                        U_ID,min(U_TIME) as U_TIME,count(rownum) as CNT
                    from 
                        USERS
                    group by 
                        U_ID)
                where 
                    CNT>1 )
;
```

If you have any primary key constraints let me know

Comment: This won't work as expected. You need to delete the oldest for each id. In order to do that, you need to correlate id's.